# How to call REST API with Oauth Header in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, rest, oauth, apache-camel, authorization

I am consuming an API with OAuth1.0 authorization. I want to make call to that API with the authorization Oauth header:-
I have created the authorization header from the token/key received from the server using- (ConsumerKey,keyalias and password) and want to send back the token or the OAuth header with the call.

I have did all these things in a Processor(Class implementing Camel Processor) and now want to do:-

1. Either call the rest API with this Oauth header(of type String) in the processor itself.
2. Else send this header in exchange and get this value in camel's `to()` endpoint and then in it call the REST API.

Thing is i just want to make rest a call in **processor** with Oauth header. 
And then if possible try to access the header in `to()` endpoint and make the call.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Authorization header in your processor and then send the REST request with `.to()`

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String token = //your logic to get the token
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
}

.to("your/rest/endpoint")
```

Camel automatically copies over the message headers onto the outgoing message.

Comment: I was not able to add header using :-


**exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", token);**

"Bearer" was not needed.

Comment: Yeah, the authorization type is most of the times not required, here is a discussion about it: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/120244

Comment: Okay. Thanks @burki for the help.