# call to oauth to get token in apache camel

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I am new to Apache Camel. I wanted to call Oauth service from my existing route and get the access token value to call another rest service. I could not find anything on web. I wanted to implement it using Spring XML.

Comment: How people can help you if you don't provide anything. No offense but stackoverflow is not a place to have your job done. However you should check internet. There is a duplicate question in SO and imho, you should check how oauth works. If that doesn't solve your problem, you should at least give the http flow of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call REST API with Oauth Header in Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346075/how-to-call-rest-api-with-oauth-header-in-apache-camel)